# How can I rotate by dragging the manipulator again? Like in the gif

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, 3d-manipulator

[image]

I can no longer grab the XYZ handles anymore in rotate, but can still grab the white one. Grabbing anywhere inside the white circle just does a free transform, not along an axis.

Not issues with grab or scale.

Tried a new project, same issue, so guessing I changed some blender setting.

Hitting R and XYZ still works, but would be nice to be able to grab again sometimes.

Also, duno if it matters, if I hover over the manipulator, it says trackball style even tho Orbit method in preferences is set to Turntable.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the orientation mode is set to global
[image]

Comment: Still fairly new. I'm almost always on global, but curious the logic. I thought that only changed the direction/orientation of the transform, now how it worked/was interacted with.